# Javascript/Appcelerator function used before defined warning

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm getting errors like this using Appcelerator/Javascript:
`[WARN] JavaScript compiler reported "'getDefaultServerFromDatabase' was used before it was defined." at includes/server.js:36`

I honestly didn't know that was an issue with Javascript.  Will it cause problems or is it just good practice?  I much prefer to have the main function first in the file then the functions it calls after that.  Should I switch this around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has not caused any differences in behavior in our application.

The only issue it causes us is to fill up the build screen with those warnings so we may miss important warnings or have to scroll to find compile errors.